# How to improve performance drawing image in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

HI'm making an application where I have to draw a certain number of images per cycle.
this number can vary with certain user actions.
When the number begins to grow to Application becomes very slow, and the speed performance is the most important to it.

At this time I draw the imgens well:

//open context

```
IGraphicsBeginImageContext(gameImage.frame.size);
```

//draw all images
//imagemref is a NSArray of UIImage

```
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(x,y, sizeX, sizeY),[[imagemref objectAtIndex:i] CGImage]);
```

//end context

```
gameImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[gameImage setAlpha:opacidade];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

if anyone has a more effective way of drawing pictures. I enjoyed learning

Comment: [gameImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, gameImage.frame.size.width, gameImage.frame.size.height)]; and CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(x,y, sizeX, sizeY),[[imagemref objectAtIndex:i] CGImage]); doing the same job of drawing image. Both are really in single method or used to draw the same image? Is it partial implementation

Comment: this line of code was over, I already took it off,
but I had no improvement in performance
thank you

Comment: At a certain point you can't really escape a limit of how many images you can draw onscreen. However, if all you are doing is drawing CGImages, build your array out of CGImages instead of UIImages. Its probably not much of a gain tho.
If you must draw a lot of images you will have to solve the problem differently. Look into SpriteKit or one of the many 2D graphics libraries out there (Cocos2d for example). They use tricks like mapping different sprites into a single texture for more efficient memory access.